# How much do arteries expand during pulse?

Tags: physiology, cardiology

Arteries expand during a pulse. The amount of expansion may differ from artery to artery. How much do arteries expand? I understand it might be a range. Inform the same. Even values specific to some arteries will be fine.

Comment: I assume you're asking about humans -- is this true, or are you asking more broadly? Also, please indicate some of your own research for this question. (See [How do I ask a good question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips for writing good questions on Bio.SE).